# Can we access the value of a member or class variable of a test class in the testListner methods

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng

I have a situation where 'xyz' is member variable of my testClass and I want to print some information in my report using that variable only.

So I want to access 'xyz' in my 'onTestFailure' listner method. Please suggest if anyone has attempted it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.

- But to achieve this you need to declare variable as a global
- Good practice will be if you could initialize when you are initializing all you driver and system details

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, declare the variable `public`.

In your listener, the `onTestFailure` method receives a `result` parameter. That `result` parameter knows the instance of the test class that threw the failure. Call the `result`'s `getInstance` method to get the instance of the test class.

To get access to the variable, first cast the instance to the right type (the type that declares the variable or method you want to access). Then fetch the variable from the instance.

Something like this:

```
public MyTestListener implements ITestListener {
    ...
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        Object instance = result.getInstance();

        MyXYZVariableType xyz = MyTestClass.class.cast(instance).xyz;

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```